# The constructor Intentis undefined

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, android-fragments

Sorry for my english but i'm new in this, and have a problem with my code cause i want add a button in my fragment for go to activity o another fragment, i dont know that if this is possible (fragment -> Activity) Please i need know what's the method for add this button.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    return rootView;

}
public void IniciarH(View v)
{
    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), IniciarHome.class);
    startActivity(intent);


}

}
```

and my .xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="159dp"
    android:onClick="IniciarH"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a clickListener to your Button

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), IniciarHome.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

return rootView;

}
```